# Is there a CSS issue on the badges page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

So, I'm looking at my badges, and my first thought is, "I have more than 59!"

[image]

Looking at the Nice Answer, that's 67 right there :)  Is this just a CSS issue, or is there an actual calculation error going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see, you have 59 *distinct* badges, even though a few of them have been awarded multiple times.

Even Jon Skeet's page has "only" 587 badges, even though he has more than 2k(!) Enlightened badges.

So, it's by design.

Comment: Should it not say then "59 Distinct Badges"?